# Calculating the absolute position of a Field in a PDF form

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to get the Absolute position of a PDF field and My code is as follows.

```
float[] _advisor = reader.getAcroFields().getFieldPositions("_advisor");
float[] _test = reader.getAcroFields().getFieldPositions("_test");
float[] _owner = reader.getAcroFields().getFieldPositions("_owner");
```

All the fields are vertically aligned same left position.

The problem is the first two fields are on the same page of the PDF and the value of xLeft is same but the Last field _owner is on the second page and the Value of xLeft is off by a big amount. Do i need to subtract an offset or something for pages in different page?

Comment: *off by a big amount* - compared to what? IText, even 
the old version you use, returns the value in the pdf as is, so it is exact. Probably, though, your expected coordinate system is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider:

- The default coordinate used by iText has its origin at the lower left corner of the page.
- iText will return coordinates in points, rather than in pixels.
- You can display a ruler and grid overlay using Adobe Reader, this enables you to easily gauge where each component is at. Check whether these readings are the same as the values iText provides you with.

If you still think iText is giving you the wrong values, please provide us access to your pdf, and provide us with the values you expect to receive (and why).

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue could be that your mediabox has a different positioning than 0,0. I needed that once so I "normalized" the values like this:

```
PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.getPageN(pageNumber);
PdfArray mediaBox = (PdfArray)PdfReader.getPdfObject(pageDict.get(PdfName.MEDIABOX));

//check whether the mediabox has a different positioning than 0,0
if(((PdfNumber)mediaBox.getPdfObject(0)).floatValue()!=0){
  //normalize X coordinates
  lowerLeftX = lowerLeftX-(PdfNumber)mediaBox.getPdfObject(0)).floatValue(); 
  upperRightX = upperRightX-((PdfNumber)mediaBox.getPdfObject(0)).floatValue(); 
}
if(((PdfNumber)mediaBox.getPdfObject(1)).floatValue()!=0){
 //normalize Y coordinates 
 lowerLeftY = lowerLeftY-((PdfNumber)mediaBox.getPdfObject(1)).floatValue();
 upperRightY = upperRightY-((PdfNumber)mediaBox.getPdfObject(1)).floatValue();
}
```